# Water from the Kohanim washing their hands by nei'lah

Tags: sources-mekorot, yom-kippur, netilat-yadayim-washing, birchas-kohanim, segulah

I heard about a minhag the other day (for the first time) and was wondering if there is any makor for it. I was told that people ran out to "catch" the water that was used to wash the Kohanim's hands before going to duchen by Nei'ilah on Yom Kippur. It's apparently a segulah for, well, something (maybe we'll find out more soon.) This minhag I have never heard or seen before (due to the fact I'm not a Kohen, Levi, or Bechor and didn't know about the minhag thus didn't run out of shul to catch the water when the Kohanim washed their hands!)

Has anyone ever heard of this? What's the makor (source)? Perhaps this has been mixed together with some other minhag?

Comment: I've never heard of this. But perhaps it's related to [this](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14556&st=&pgnum=348) (see #757 and Kuntres Acharon #13).

Comment: Very curious practice considering the ban on washing on _YK_.

Comment: @msh210 with the minimal amount of water that there already is I'm assuming there is even less to "catch" in this case -- my brother-in-law (a chassidishe yid from Yerushalayim) told me about this

Comment: @Yehoshua, why do you say "minimal amount of water"? The halocho is that the Cohanim have to get washed properly, even on YK - the entire hand up to the wrist. (And I've never heard of this, despite being a Levi - and I can't figure out how they get around the issur of washing on YK as well as the Issur of touching water that was used for washing which would require one to wash ones hands.)

Comment: @DannySchoemann didn't know that was the halacha/minhag. Like I said I'm not a cohen, levi, or bechor and don't get out so much during this time on Yom Kippur

Comment: In the Shuls that I am aware of there is no Birchas Kohanim at Neila as it is way past Shekiya?

Comment: @GershonGold That's because you live in the Diaspora where Ashkenazim don't duchen anyway. In Israel it is common practice to finish Neila before sunset so that Duchening can take place.

Comment: @msh210 I assumed he meant 'catch' in a cup for use later, because indeed this would certainly be biblically prohibited otherwise.

Comment: @DannySchoemann I wasn't aware there is ever a _prohibition_ on touching water that was used for washing hands, certainly in this case where the washing is for cleanliness/preparation and not to remove ruach ra'.

Comment: @DoubleAA: Even in Shuls in Israel that I have Davened in they finish too late for Birchas Kohanim @ Neila

Comment: @DoubleAA you have a point there; Ruach Ra (and ensuring the water doesn't come in contact with people) is only mentioned for Negel Vasser (Kitzur SA 2:4) and Mayim Achronim (ibid 44:2)